# NSString attribute is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Using 3rd font that works in other cases, trying to bold some text :

```
 NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 5);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:timeString];

    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic-Bold" size:[Globals sharedGlobals].16.0+2.0]
                       range:boldedRange];

    [attrString endEditing];


       cell.next.text=[attrString string];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
   cell.next.attributedText=attrString;
```